# Why submitting this form it submits wrong ids?

Tags: php, html, submit, form-submit

I am submitting this from and in the same page getting the values of the $_POST['id] and displaying them but its getting the wrong id not the ones I am selecting from the row in the table:

```
 <tbody>
         <?php if (!empty($found_devices)) {
                                    foreach ($found_devices as $devs) : ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="display_hide_selectClient(this)" name="devices[<?php echo $devs["id"] ?>]" value="<?php echo $devs["id"] ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo $devs["serial_imei"] ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo $devs["serial_no"] ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo $devs["created_date"] ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input hidden name="edit_device_imei" value="<?php echo $devs["serial_imei"] ?>">
                                                <input hidden name="edit_device_serial" value="<?php echo $devs["serial_no"] ?>">
                                                <input hidden name="edit_device_id" value="<?php echo $devs["id"] ?>">
                                                <button type="submit" name="edit_device">Edit</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                <?php endforeach;
                                } ?>
                            </tbody>
```

So, when submitting this form with the button `edit_device` I am receiving the wrong values in PHP.

PHP Ccode:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_device']) && !empty($_POST['edit_device_id'])) {
  $get_selected_Devices = e($_POST['edit_device_id']);
  $get_selected_Devices_s = e($_POST['edit_device_serial']);
  $get_selected_Devices_i = e($_POST['edit_device_imei']);
}
```

Comment: Won't it always contain the id of the last one in the loop, because you don't use an array indicator in those last three hidden input fields? In any case, what value should it get, and what _does_ it get? Wouldn't it be easier to have a separate `<form>` pair around each entry, rather than putting them all in one?

Comment: Since you are adding all of these inputs in a loop, the very last loop will always replace any inputs before it. If you want a "submit" button for each row of your table, each row needs it's own `<form>` element wrapping it.